# ORSSerialPort with Arduino

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, arduino, orsserialport

I've been trying for a long time to program an Xcode interface to communicate with my Arduino Mega. but the whole thing didn't work as well as intended. I did the whole thing with ORSSerialPort.

In the Xcode project I wrote this for the swift file ViewController.swift :

```
import Cocoa
import ORSSerial


class ViewController: NSViewController, ORSSerialPortDelegate {

var serialPort = ORSSerialPort(path: "/dev/cu.usbmodem142101")
    
 
    
    func SendString(data: String){
                let stringData = Data(data.utf8)
                serialPort?.send(stringData)
            }
    func openPort(){
                serialPort?.baudRate=9600
                serialPort?.delegate=self
                serialPort?.parity = .none
                serialPort?.numberOfStopBits = 1
                serialPort?.open()
                print("serialport is open")
            }
    func closePort(){
                serialPort?.delegate=nil
                serialPort?.close()
                print("serialport is close")
            }
    
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        }
    }
 
  
    
    @IBAction func onButton(_ sender: Any) {
        openPort()
    }
    @IBAction func OffButton(_ sender: Any) {
        closePort()
    }
    @IBAction func SendButton(_ sender: Any) {
        SendString(data: "stringdata blablabla")
    }

    
    
    
    func serialPortWasOpened(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort) {
        print("serialPort to \(serialPort) is run")
    }

    func serialPortWasRemovedFromSystem(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort) {
        self.serialPort = nil
    }
    
}
```

and this code i have load on the Arduino mega:

```
String angel;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 
 
 angel = Serial.readString();

 Serial.println(angel);
 delay(350);

}
```

unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Max, can you add more detail about what doesn't work? Do you see the messages logged indicating that the serial port was opened (ie. "serialPort to /dev/cu.usbmodem142101 is run")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide any detail about what part(s) don't work, but there's one definite problem.

Your Arduino program looks like it echoes everything it receives on the serial port back on the same port. In order to see that on the computer, you'll have to implement the `serialPort(_:didReceive:)` method in your view controller. Something like this:

```
func serialPort(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort, didReceive data: Data) {
    guard let string = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii) else { return; }
    print("Received: \(string)")
}
```